# Spring Integration and AMQP: How to gracefully handle deserialization exceptions?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I use **RabbitMQ** and **Spring Integration** to handle **incoming JSON messages**.

The relevant part of the configuration looks something like this:

```
<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="incomingChannel" queue-names="..."
      message-converter="jsonConverter" error-handler="errorHandler"
      error-channel="errorChannel" />
```

I'm using Jackson Databind as the JSON converter.

Sometimes the incoming JSON messages have an **incorrect syntax**. This results in the following (correct) exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token...
```

The exception is then handled by the `errorHandler` which simply is a `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` to `errorChannel`.

So far so good. The problem is, that the message is still being rejected by the AMQP client, although I am handling it with an error handler. RabbitMQ then redelivers the message over and over. Even configuring a dead letter queue did not help. Any ideas how to handle this scenario correctly?

Exceptions further down the processing (after successful deserialization) are handled just fine: AMQP message acknowledged and error message sent to `errorChannel`.

Any ideas?

Library versions:

- Spring Integration: 3.0.1
- Spring Framework: 4.0.2
- Jackson Databind: 2.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `defaultRequeueRejected=false` on the listener container.

The attribute is not currently exposed on the channel adapter, but you can define the container as a `<bean... class="...SimpleMessageListenerContainer"/>` and inject it into adapter using the `listener-container` attribute.

Or, use a custom `ErrorHandler` that throws an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

Comment: My mistake, the `requeue-rejected` setting is indeed available when using `<rabbit:listener-container/>`; I forgot that we added it some time ago.